# How to remove quote characters around array when loading a csv in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, csv, quotation-marks

I am having trouble removing quote characters that appear around my arrays.
When I read in my file like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('filepath.csv', sep='|', index_col=0, nrows=5)
```

the dtype of my problematic column is `object` but the individual entries are strings:

```
print(type(data.body_tokens[0]))
data.body_tokens[0]
```

```
<class 'str'>
"['he', 'knows', 'what', 'he', 's', 'doing']"
```

How can I remove the quotation marks around the array?

Comment: What's the original CSV data?

Comment: That isn't an array, that's a string.

Comment: Do you want a file?

Comment: Well, in my csv file there are no quotation marks

Comment: It is meant as an array, sorry.

Comment: You just see quotation marks because you're looking at the repr of a string. The real issue is, do you want this to be a string, or do you expect this to be a list? Because it's a string in your CSV as well, just that you don't see the quotes there because, well, it's not a Python repr. If you do `print(data.body_tokens[0])` instead you'll get it without quotes; but is that really useful to you?

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are trying to use the csv format for something it wasn't designed to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import ast

string = "['he', 'knows', 'what', 'he', 's', 'doing']"

list = ast.literal_eval(string)

type(list)    #list

print(list)   #['he', 'knows', 'what', 'he', 's', 'doing']
```

want this one?